# Discord.js command handler bot doesn't respond

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Hello I have a very big problem with command handler with which I am struggling for a long time, the thing is that my bot after adding a command does not respond as I type it, I tried several methods from youtube but none of them works, for any help thank you very much
code below!

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require('./config.json')
const prefix = '$';
const fs = require('fs');


client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!')
});

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on('message', async message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    console.log(message.content);

    if (command === `${prefix}ping`) {
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    }

}); 

client.login(config.token);

ping.js FILE!

module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'komenda ping',
    execute(message, args) {
        message.channel.send('Pong!');
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `command` will never be `${prefix}ping` as you've already removed the prefix from the message using `.slice(prefix.length)`. Check and run the snippet below:

```js
const prefix = '!'
const message = {
  content: '!ping it now'
}

const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ')
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase()

console.log({'message.content': message.content, command, args})
```

To fix it, you need to check if the command is the string `"ping"`:

```js
if (command === 'ping') {
  client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args)
}
```